# Cannot execute CSS code using JavaScript on a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to give a sliding effect using left and right DIVs when user clicks in the middle DIV(blue). But it's not working.

The script code is not working. I think there is some error.

When I used hover in my stylesheet it also didn't work. I mean that I used hover on id inner/outer/power which will change css property of id left and right to create a sliding transition effect. But it didn't work. But when I used container to be hovered instead of the above ids then sliding effect was working. I'm totally depressed as it's not making any sense to me.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" >
 function slide()
 {
  document.getElementById("left").style.left = -100% ;
  document.getElementById("right").style.right = -100% ;
 }
</script>
```

```css
html,body{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
#container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;

}

#left {
 left: 0px;
 margin-left: 0%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: yellow;

 transition: left ease-out 3s;
 
}
#right {
 right: 0px;
 margin-left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: green;
 transition: right ease-out 3s;
}

#outer{
 z-index: 5;
 margin-left: 47.5%;
    margin-top: 25%;
 width: 5%;
 position: absolute;
}

#inner {
 z-index: 5;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
   
}

#power {
 z-index: 5;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<div id="container">
 <div id="outer">
 <div id="inner" >
 <a href="javascript:slide()">
  <img id="power" src="off.png">
  </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="left"></div>
 <div id="right"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `style.left = -100%` – that’s wrong (and I would be rather surprised if this would not generate JS error messages in console) – it needs to be a string value, `style.left = "-100% "`

Comment: Thanks for the help CBroe !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for your CSS effect needs to be in quotations.

```js
 function slide()
 {
  document.getElementById("left").style.left = "-100%";
  document.getElementById("right").style.right = "-100%" ;
 }
```

```css
html,body{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
#container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;

}

#left {
 left: 0px;
 margin-left: 0%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: yellow;

 transition: left ease-out 3s;
 
}
#right {
 right: 0px;
 margin-left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: green;
 transition: right ease-out 3s;
}

#outer{
 z-index: 5;
 margin-left: 47.5%;
    margin-top: 25%;
 width: 5%;
 position: absolute;
}

#inner {
 z-index: 5;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
   
}

#power {
 z-index: 5;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<div id="container">
 <div id="outer">
 <div id="inner" >
 <a href="javascript:slide()">
  <img id="power" src="off.png">
  </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="left"></div>
 <div id="right"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As a side note, in code snippets, your JavaScript does not need to be inside of the script tag, as long as it is in the JavaScript section.

Comment: HAHAHAAAAAA .............. THANK YOUUUUU SOOOO MUCHHHH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome, and did you see my note at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: Hey are you on Facebook ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("left").style.left = "-100px";
```